# Unable to open a file from different directory in Python running in Windows

Tags: python

I am unable to open a file which is located in a directory.

Please see the code below:

```
file = open("E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt","w")
```

but I am getting the following error while opening the file.

```
   E:\Python_Scratch
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you please help me out on how to open the file?

Comment: can you post the whole code? There is no invalid syntax on that line

Answer (score 0):

In Python a backslash inside a string is used to give comands like newline (`\n`).

So, if you want to write a backslash, instead of giving a command, use two backslashes:

`file = open("E:\\Python_Scratch\\test.txt","w")`

You can consult the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for more informaiton about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are in Windows OS, try this format

```
file = open(r"E:\\Python_Scratch\test.txt","w")
#raw path(string) by r before ''
#after drive name :\\ double slash,  you will be fine if you use single or double slashes after next path(one dir deep) and on-wards.
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting a parenthesis on a previous line gives your error in Python 2.x.  Example:

```
x = (
print("E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt")
```

Output:

```
  File "test.py", line 2
    print("E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also, with Python strings, single backslashes may be interpreted as escape codes.  In your case, `\t` is a tab:

```
>>> print("E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt")
E:\Python_Scratch       est.txt
```

Instead. use double backslashes to indicate you want one real backslash in the string, or use raw strings (note the leading `r`):

```
>>> print(r"E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt")
E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt
>>> print("E:\\Python_Scratch\\test.txt")
E:\Python_Scratch\test.txt
```